# How can I query an associative table with matching "where" conditions with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to retrieve products that belong to multiple collections using sequelize.
Dialect is Postgres and I'm using Sequelize 4.15.1

I have a Product model, a Collection model and the associative model CollectionProduct. Product belongs to many collections and collection belongs to many products.

Product model:

```
const Product = sequelize.define( 'Product', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  } );
  Product.associate = function( models ) {
    Product.belongsToMany( models.Collection, {
      through: models.CollectionProduct
    } );
  }
```

Collection model:

```
const Collection = sequelize.define( 'Collection', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  slug: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
} );
Collection.associate = function( models ) {
  Collection.belongsToMany( models.Product, {
    through: models.CollectionProduct
  } );
}
```

Here is my sequelize query

```
models.Product.findAll( {
  attributes: ["id", "name"],
  include: [ {
    model: models.Collection,
    attributes: ["id", "name", "slug"],
    where: {
      slug: {
        [Op.like]: { [Op.all]: ['collection-a', 'collection-b']}
      }
    }
  } ]
} ).then( products => {
  console.log( products )
} ).catch( function ( err ) {
  console.log( err );
} );
```

Here is the generated postgres query

```
SELECT "Product"."id",
       "Product"."name",
       "Collections"."id" AS "Collections.id",
       "Collections"."name" AS "Collections.name",
       "Collections"."slug" AS "Collections.slug",
       "Collections->CollectionProduct"."createdAt" AS "Collections.CollectionProduct.createdAt",
       "Collections->CollectionProduct"."updatedAt" AS "Collections.CollectionProduct.updatedAt",
       "Collections->CollectionProduct"."CollectionId" AS "Collections.CollectionProduct.CollectionId",
       "Collections->CollectionProduct"."ProductId" AS "Collections.CollectionProduct.ProductId"
FROM "Products" AS "Product"
INNER JOIN ("CollectionProducts" AS "Collections->CollectionProduct"
            INNER JOIN "Collections" AS "Collections" ON "Collections"."id" = "Collections->CollectionProduct"."CollectionId") ON "Product"."id" = "Collections->CollectionProduct"."ProductId"
AND "Collections"."slug" LIKE ALL (ARRAY['collection-a',
                                         'collection-b']);
```

I'd like to return the products that belong to both collection A and B.

Unfortunately the query execution does not return any result.

Comment: Just curious: do you set the model of CollectionProduct yourself (a 'custom joint table'), or have sequelize generate it?

Comment: I defined the model `'use strict';
module.exports = function( sequelize, DataTypes ) {
  const CollectionProduct = sequelize.define( 'CollectionProduct');
  return CollectionProduct;
};
`

Comment: but Sequelize generates the relationship automatically

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick. Grabs all productid's intersecting between collection-a id's and collection-b id's.

```
select
  t1.slug as slug_ca,
  t2.slug as slug_cb,
  t1.productid
from
(
  select
    p3.slug,
    p1.id as productid
  from products p1
       inner join collectionproducts p2
         on p1.id = p2.ProductId
       inner join collections p3
         on p2.CollectionId = p3.id
  where lower(p3.slug) like '%collection-a%'
  group by 1,2
) t1
inner join
(
  select
    p3.slug,
    p1.id as productid
  from products p1
       inner join collectionproducts p2
         on p1.id = p2.ProductId
       inner join collections p3
         on p2.CollectionId = p3.id
  where lower(p3.slug) like '%collection-b%'
  group by 1,2
) t2
  on t1.productid = t2.productid
group by 1,2,3;
```

Comment: Query works! Thanks! it is just hard to programmatically implement that. If I want to query x numbers of collection for instance, not sure how to make it work.